# How to iterate through specific elements in a vector C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, iteration, sfml, game-development

I'm making a game with C++ and SFML and was wondering if there's a way to iterate through specific elements in a vector. I have a vector of tiles which makes up the game world, but depending on the game map's size, (1000 x 1000 tiles) iterating through all of them seems very inefficient. I was wondering if there was a way to say "for each tile in vector of tiles that (fits a condition)". Right now, my code for drawing these tiles looks like this:

```
void Tile::draw()
{
    for (const auto& TILE : tiles)
    {
        if (TILE.sprite.getGlobalBounds().intersects(Game::drawCuller.getGlobalBounds()))
        {
            Game::window.draw(TILE.sprite);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm only *drawing* the tiles in the view (or drawculler). If the vector is too large, it will take a really long time to iterate through it. This greatly impacts my fps. When I have a 100 x 100 tile map, I get around 800 fps, but when I use a 1000 x 1000 tile map, I get roughly 25 fps due to the lengthy iteration. I know that I could separate my tiles into chunks and only iterate through the ones in the current chunk, but I wanted something a little easier to implement. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Iterating a 1000x1000 map in C++ should take in the order of milliseconds. The real problem lies in what you are doing for each tile. That's probably what needs optimization

Comment: As of right now, I'm only drawing the ones in the view to the screen. The tiles have no logic or collision detection or anything. They are just being drawn.

Comment: Is the `draw` function you've shown supposed to be drawing all the tiles, or just the current tile (i.e. `this`)?

Comment: It's a static function that loops through all the tiles and draws the ones that can be seen in the view.

Comment: depends **very much** on the nature of the condition.  If it's something that doesn't change often from update to update then you may want to add the appropriate tiles to a another collection. e.g. keep a list of which tiles are on fire to efficiently select which tiles may spread flame to adjacent tiles.  You may also be able to process tiles in round robin batches of N per update.

Comment: Try build a (presumably smaller) container containing either `TILE` (or, maybe pointers to elements of `tiles`, particularly if copying a `TILE` is expensive) that meet your condition, and iterate over that.   There are various tools in the standard library to help with that (e.g. `std::copy_if()`, `std::remove_if()`, ).   It's hard to be more specific, without information on how you select the subset (e.g. how expensive is it to check for the condition?)

Comment: Isn't it slower to iterate through pointers to objects and derefrence them?

Comment: Slower than what?    Iterating over a small container of pointers and dereferencing can be much faster that iterating over a much larger container of objects.       It all comes down to how expensive it is to create the smaller container (e.g. how expensive is it to evaluate the condition that identifies the subset of objects you want) and how expensive it is to do some work on a smaller set of objects versus doing the same work on a much larger set of objects.   You're the one who said you wanted to operate over a subset of objects.

Comment: sizeof(tile) returns 297 bytes -_-. In this case, I should be using unique_ptr<Tile> rather than Tile objects in my vector right? Also, when should I opt for ptrs rather than objects in my vector?

Comment: If you store your tiles in a 2-dimensional array, then you can compute the range of x and y coordinates to iterate through.  If your tile list is fully populated then you can compute the one-dimensional index of a tile from its x,y  (usually `y * width + x`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following assumptions:

- Your tiles are likely arranged on a regular grid with a (column, row) index.
- Your tiles are likely inserted into your vector in row-major order, and is also likely fully-populated.  So the index of a tile in your vector is likely `(row * numColumns + column)`.
- Your view is likely axis-aligned to the grid (where you can't rotate your view - as is the case with many 2d tile-based games)

If those assumptions hold true, then you can easily iterate through the appropriate range of tiles with a nested loop.

```
for (int row = minRow; row <= maxRow; ++row) {
   for( int column = numColumn; column <= maxColumn; ++column) {
      int index = row * numColumns + column;

      // Here you can...
      doSomethingWith(tiles[index]);
   }
}
```

This just requires that you can compute the `minRow`, `maxRow`, `minColumn`, and `maxColumn` from your `Game::drawCuller.getGlobalBounds()`.  You haven't disclosed the details, but it's likely something like a rectangle in world coordinates (which might be in some units like meters). It's likely either a `left`, `top`, `width`, `height` style rectangle or a `min`, `max` style bounds rectangle.  Assuming the latter:

```
minViewColumn = floor((bounds.minInMeters.x - originOfGridInMeters.x) / gridTileSizeInMeters);
maxViewColumn = ceil((bounds.maxInMeters.x - originOfGridInMeters.x) / gridTileSizeInMeters);
// similarly for rows
minViewRow = floor((bounds.minInMeters.y - originOfGridInMeters.y) / gridTileSizeInMeters);
maxViewRow = ceil((bounds.maxInMeters.y - originOfGridInMeters.y) / gridTileSizeInMeters);
```

The `originOfGridInMeters` is the global coordinates of top-left corner of the tile at (row=0, column=0), which may very well be (0, 0), conveniently, if you set up your world like that.  And `gridTileSizeInMeters` is, well, just that; presumably your tiles have a square aspect ratio in world space.

If the view is permitted to go outside the extents of the tile array, `minViewColumn`, (and the other iterator ranges) may now be less than 0 or greater than or equal to the number of columns in your tile array.  So, it would then be necessary to compute `minColumn` from `minViewColumn` by **clipping** it to the range of tiles stored in your grid. (Same goes for the other iteration extents.)

```
// Clip to the range of valid rows and columns.
minColumn = min(max(minViewColumn, 0), numColumns - 1);
maxColumn = min(max(maxViewColumn, 0), numColumns - 1);
minRow = min(max(minViewRow, 0), numRows - 1);
maxRow = min(max(maxViewRow, 0), numRows - 1);
```

Now do that loop I showed you above, and you're good to go!

Comment: Unless the author of the question wants to render to a non-rectangular screen with holes in it, this answer is on point :)

Comment: thank you for such an in depth answer. I'll add my player to the game so that the view can be moved around, then I'll try this method out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if there was a way to say "for each tile in vector of tiles that (fits a condition)

In general, no.  The only way to know if an element fits a condition is to look at it and see if it fits the condition.  You can't do that without iterating over all the elements and checking the condition for each.

The way to avoid this is to build some sort of index structure.  For instance, if you have tiles with attributes that change rarely, you could pre-build vectors of pointers to all of your tiles with some attribute.  That way you can check the condition only once (or rarely) instead of on each frame.  For instance you could build separate vectors of all of your blue tiles, all of your red tiles, and all of your green tiles.  Then if you want to iterate over all of the tiles of a certain color you could do "for each blue tile" directly instead of "for each tile, if it's blue".  This generally trades storage/memory usage for execution speed.

The same concept applies to your specific situation, as you mentioned.  You can pre-build caches of chunks, and quickly filter out whole chunks that aren't near your camera.  This will prevent you from having to check every tile to see if it's in view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know if there are any std algorithms that allow you to loop through specific elements? Otherwise, I'll look into making a chunk system for my game's entities.

Comment: With C++20 ranges you could use [`std::ranges::filter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view).  For example: `auto visible_tiles = std::ranges::filter([&](const auto& tile) { return tile.intersects(camera); }); for (const auto& tile : visible_tiles) { ... }`  IMO it's not particularly shorter or more readable than the `for each { if ... }` version though.

Comment: I can give it a try and benchmark the performance real quick ;)

Comment: how do I get access to std::ranges::filter? I'm using C++ 20, but its an invalid algorithm.

Comment: Use a very recent compiler.  See [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20) for more info on which compiler versions support which C++20 features.

Comment: is there another filtering algo that you know of? I can't see std::ranges::filter on cpprefrence either.

Comment: There's [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to copy elements that match a condition from one container to another, but there were no lazy view transformations in the standard library pre C++20 ranges.  You could, of course use the [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library that the standard ranges are based on, but that's a third party library.

Comment: I tried this algorithm: auto visibleTiles = tiles | std::ranges::views::filter([](const Tile& TILE)
  {
   return TILE.sprite.getGlobalBounds().intersects(Game::drawCuller.getGlobalBounds());
  });

and it didn't affect my framerate. It's still at 25 fps. Idk

Comment: Right, I would expect it to run exactly the same.  It's doing the exact same thing, just pulling the `if` out into the `filter` view.  Unless you do some sort of indexing there's no way around iterating through every tile in the container to check if it's on camera.